# What is 'rvm_codesign_identity' and how to set it?

Tags: ruby, rvm, codesign

I'm using rvm 1.16.10 (stable)

After I did `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

it installed 1.9.3 and then shows:`'rvm_codesign_identity' is not set, please set it in ~/.rvmrc`

But.. What is 'rvm_codesign_identity' and how to set it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/820
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1210#issuecomment-9272236

> `rvm_codesign_identity` is parameter for codesign utility on OSX to sign compiled binary ruby so it does not require authorization to use network - but the code is not finished or documented properly, please open a new pull request if you can help with improving this hook.

So probably no point setting it.